# Why converting float to binary GUI doesn't work?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm not sure why I keep getting errors in my code. It complies correctly, but when I run the code it gives me an error. I first completed this in the console but I decided to use a simple GUI instead and I'm having troubles. Here's the code:I didn't use the other methods yet because I am first trying to get the code to work for the first Button before I create any other.

```
public class ComputingArithmetic extends JPanel {

    JButton numToBit;
    JTextField tNumToBit, tNumToBit2, tBitToNum;
    public ComputingArithmetic(){

        JButton numToBit = new JButton("Decimal to 32 Bit");
        numToBit.addActionListener(new NumToBitListener());
        JTextField tNumToBit = new JTextField(3);
        JTextField tNumToBit2 = new JTextField(8);

        add(numToBit);
        add(tNumToBit);
        add(tNumToBit2);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 100));
    }
    public static void main(String []args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ComputingArithmetic compute = new ComputingArithmetic();
        frame.getContentPane().add(compute);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class NumToBitListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tNumToBit2.setText(DecimalToBit(Float.parseFloat(tNumToBit.getText())));
        }
    }
    private static float BitToDecimal( String Binary ) {
        int intBits = Integer.parseInt(Binary, 2);
        float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
        return myFloat;
    }
    private static String DecimalToBit( float value ) {
        if(value > 0) {
            int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(value);
            String binary = Long.toBinaryString(intBits);
            return "0"+binary;
        }
        else{
            int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(value);
            String binary = Long.toBinaryString(intBits);
            return binary;
        }
    }
    private static String HexToBit(String binary){return Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(binary,2));}
    private static String BitToHex(String binary){
        Long i = Long.parseLong(binary, 16);
        Float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(i.intValue());
        return f.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? If you're asking about errors in your code, you should list the error(s) in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you are assigning your text fields to local variables. The instance fields remain null, causing a `NullPointerException` when your `ActionListener` is called.

```
JTextField tNumToBit = new JTextField(3);
JTextField tNumToBit2 = new JTextField(8);
```

should be:

```
tNumToBit = new JTextField(3);
tNumToBit2 = new JTextField(8);
```

Comment: Man thanks so much! it was right in front on my face. I can't thank you enough!